# Swift Constant Assignment Example

Tags: ios, swift, constants

I'm a long time developer (java, c, c++, etc.) and a Swift newbie with a question.  In the switch statement below where the constant "x" is defined the example states **"Notice how let can be used in a pattern to assign the value that matched the pattern to a constant."**.  I'm a bit confused as the statement does not reference the target variable of the switch statement "vegetable" at all.  My thought is it should read:

```
case let x where vegetable.hasSuffix("pepper"):
        -- or just --
case let x where hasSuffix("pepper"):
```

and not

```
    case let x where x.hasSuffix("pepper"):
```

Any feedback will be appreciated.

[Swift Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html)

```
let vegetable = "red pepper"
switch vegetable {
case "celery":
    print("Add some raisins and make ants on a log.")
case "cucumber", "watercress":
    print("That would make a good tea sandwich.")
case let x where x.hasSuffix("pepper"):
    print("Is it a spicy \(x)?")
default:
    print("Everything tastes good in soup.")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `where` predicate *could* directly reference `vegetable`, *this this particular situation*, and it compiles fine.

```
switch vegetable {
case "celery":
    print("Add some raisins and make ants on a log.")
case "cucumber", "watercress":
    print("That would make a good tea sandwich.")
case let x where vegetable.hasSuffix("pepper"):
    print("Is it a spicy \(x)?")
default:
    print("Everything tastes good in soup.")
}
```

But now consider a more complex patternmatching of `vegetable`, supposing that it were a `String?` (a.k.a. `Optional<String>`) and not `String`:

```
let vegetable: String? = "red pepper"
switch vegetable {
case "celery"?:
    print("Add some raisins and make ants on a log.")
case "cucumber"?, "watercress"?:
    print("That would make a good tea sandwich.")
case let x? where vegetable.hasSuffix("pepper"):
    //            ^ error: value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
    print("Is it a spicy \(x)?")
case nil:
    print("You don't even have a vegetable!")
default:
    print("Everything tastes good in soup.")
}
```

In this case, `x` is the non-optional value of `vegetable` in a non-nil case, which allows use to call `.hasSuffix("pepper")` on it. It's saying "If it is the case that vegetable has a value, call it `x`, that happens to end with `"pepper"`, then do this: ..."

Comment: Thanks for the response Alexander.  The nil case is interesting but I’m not clear on the original example where they use “x.hasSuffix()”.   When or where is x being assigned the switch target value of vegetable to check if it contains the suffix?

Comment: `When or where is x being assigned the switch target value of vegetable` that's part of the semantics of `let` in pattern matching. In a non-exhaustive switch like this, each pattern is tried from top to bottom, and when all previous cases didn't match, this one is triggered. It's much like an `if let x = ...` statement.

Comment: It’s the “x.” Of “x.hasSuffix()” that is confusing to me.  From my experience that statement says that x will be pattern matched not vegetable.  X is being assigned a value based upon a pattern match on something that was never assigned a value other than the Swift default for a constant.  My expectation is that case will never be triggered.  I would try the code but my dev environment isn’t ready yet.

Comment: Also, as I understand Swift constants, a constant defined with Let is immutable so how can a constant be defined as a result of an operation upon the constant itself?

Comment: `that statement says that x will be pattern matched not vegetable.` -> No, it is vegetable that is being pattern matched. `x` is a temporary name bound to the target of the switch (`vegetable`), for the sake of discussion within the case's `where` clause.

Comment: @zappullae `X is being assigned a value based upon a pattern match` -> No, `x` is a temporary variable that is conditionally bound. It's used as part of the pattern matching. `x` is set to the value of `vegetable`, and its where clause is evaluated. If the `where` clause is satisfied (is true), then `x` "can stay", the `case` will be entered, and `x` will be available. Otherwise, the case is passed over, and it's as if `x` was never bound

Comment: @zappullae `was never assigned a value other than the Swift default for a constant` Swift doesn't have any default values, except for `nil` for optionals vars.

Comment: @zappullae  `I would try the code but my dev environment isn’t ready yet.` -> You can just try a Swift playground, the Swift REPL in terminal (just type `swift`), or you could try https://repl.it/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167578/discussion-between-alexander-and-zappullae).

Answer (score 0):

After chatting with @Alexander I have a better understanding of the switch construct.  Thanks to him for time and explanations.

As detailed in the "value bindings" section of this [Control Constructs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID120) documentation I learned that switch statements assign temporary variables to the value of the switch target before the cases are evaluated.  So that the right side (temporary x) is assigned the switch target value "red pepper" and the cases pattern matched for each switch case, top to bottom.  If the case matches then left side x becomes a permanent constant. Net net, temporary x is defined and set = vegetable then the switch pattern match performed.

```
 case let x where x.hasSuffix("pepper"):
```